# Troubleshooting database connection

Tags: database, error

I got problem with my website database, as you can see in the attached image below. Unfortunately My Dev and I have no idea what's going on. I think this trouble occurred after WP installation.. For temporary solution, we just restart the server every this error happens. Is there any suggestion how should we fix this trouble?

[image]

Comment: We're probably unlikely to be able to help with this here. It's very specific to the individual code in use in your application. You'd need to ask your dev or... find a dev who knows how to resolve it.

Comment: Actually, this sounds to be like your database has shutdown for some reason or simply has become unresponsive - likely an error or a bad query such as producing a cartesian product. Have you checked your database log files for clues?? Look specifically at nested query result sets. This takes a keen eye and if you are not a DBA, it can be easy to find, but not so easy to understand.

Comment: You may also be running out of connections due to bad queries that never complete. Again, think cartesian product where the query runs in a tight loop with no result. It is often a condition that is being produced a result set that will always exist and never end. In my comment, I was thinking you were thrashing the system, but then I remembered that you could also be running out of connections because your queries never end and keep the connections open. Again, check your log files for the query. In fact, this one makes the most sense to me right now.

Comment: @closetnoc Thanks for your reply. I'll check the log.

Comment: You don't provide enough information to solve the issue.   At a minimum you should edit your question to provide any relevant information from log files.

Comment: Stephen is perfectly right! Without further details, we cannot say what the problem is except more generally. Due to the nature of this error, based upon my experience, we, on this end, may not be able to get to a specific cause. These take real bird-dogging and getting into the weeds often using the EXPLAIN command within your database. We can get you started, but may not be able to, in this forum, get to the nub of things in your scenario. This is unfortunate. However, I am sure I got you a road-map to get started anyway! Cheers!!